# System.Linq.Expression.Compile error

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda

I have problem trying to create dynamic lambda expressions. Something on the parameters. Does anyone experienced this?

this code need create the follow lambda:

```
{x => x.Core.Where(core => core.Members.Where(members => members.Name.ToUpper().Contains("LOK")).Any()).Any()}
```

but get error in Compile method.

Error message:

> Variable 'core' of type 'TesteLambdaParameter.Models.Class2'
>   referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

```
Predicate = {x => x.Core.Where(core => core.Members.Where(members => members.Name.ToUpper().Contains("LOK")).Any()).Any()}
```

My code:

```
Func<T, bool> compiled = predicate.Compile(); // <<== Error Here
    // Error message: Variable 'core' of type 'TesteLambdaParameter.Models.Class2' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

Comment: To help us help you, please edit your question such that it is a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dav_i That is a minimal to run that, I Rip all satelite code like Verify and Cast Types, Transform to ExpressionConstant, etc...

Comment: I find it extremely unlikely that it's minimal to the problem that you're having though, you need to strip it back to the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK, but I think this way is very difficult to identify what might be happening.

Comment: You've gone too far the other way now :). Create a new program, which does what you're trying to do with as few elements as possible - you never know, you might figure out the problem doing that - in which case feel free to post the answer here too!

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved.**

The method was called recursively, creating the parameter and the expression and returned to himself. In this process the parameters were removed from memory, as they had already been used believed not to have problems. But they need to be kept in memory until the time of compilation. In this case I used a private variable to store the parameters that have been using thus compiled correctly.